# why does using + still match an empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this regex put empty strings into the beginning and end of the matches array?

```
var s = "1111abcd2222";

var re = /(\d+)([a-z]*?)(\d+)/g;

console.log(s.split(re)); //=>"", "1", "abcd", "2222", ""]
```

I thought the `+` operator would avoid empty string matches becuase it requires a minimum of one character.

Comment: Because you used `split` instead of `match`?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the start and end indicator:

```
var re = /^(\d+)([a-z]*?)(\d+)$/g;
//        ^- start            ^ -end
```

The string `aa1bb` can get matched by `/([a-z]+)\d([a-z]+)/` as just `a1b` because it doesn't have to be greedy. If you use `/^([a-z]+)\d([a-z]+)$/` you indicate that it must start matching at the beginning and stop at the end, so it will match `aa1bb` giving `[ "aa1bb", "aa", "bb" ]`

You're getting empty strings at the start and end because you're using `split`.

```
"aaa".split(/a/); // [ "", "", "", "" ]
"abab".split(/(ab)/); // [ "", "ab", "", "ab", "" ]
```

Comment: `/^(\d+)([a-z]*?)(\d+)$/` still gives me empty strings at the end when matching on the string in my question however.

Comment: You're using `split`, it's a full match so the other parts are empty. Like `"aaa".split("a")` gives you 4 empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `String#match` instead of `String#split` here.

However if you do want to use split then following negative lookahead based regex will avoid empty results:

```
re = /(?!^)(\d+)([a-z]*?)(\d+)(?!$)/g;
//=> ["1", "111", "abcd", "222", "2"]
```